# CSP refused API Twitter

Tags: api, security, twitter, twitter-oauth

When i try authenticate, the redirect URL for it  has a response `400`:

> api.twitter.com/oauth2/token?oauth_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:1
>   GET
>   https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token?oauth_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   400 () /oauth2/token?oauth_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:1 Refused
>   to apply inline style because it violates the following Content
>   Security Policy directive: "style-src https://abs.twimg.com
>   https://abs-0.twimg.com". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
>   ('sha256-4Su6mBWzEIFnH4pAGMOuaeBrstwJN4Z3pq/s1Kn4/KQ='), or a nonce
>   ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

In my page "connect twitter" has a meta CSP:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;
style-src 'self' http://* https://* 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self'
http://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * data:" />
```

Whats going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's complaining about Twitter's CSP directive and not your own.

You can see their directive [here](https://securityheaders.io/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2Foauth2%2Ftoken%3Foauth_token%3Dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx), and it contains the following:

```
style-src https://abs.twimg.com https://abs-0.twimg.com
```

Which directly matches the error message.

Why Twitter are apparently blocking their own api call I don't know.

Btw on a separate note I think your syntax is wrong as don't think https://* is allowed, and it should be:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' http: https: 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' http: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * data:" />
```

Comment: FWIW, the CSP message is related to a Chrome issue where it attempts to apply a default styling to text responses; https://crbug.com/766965

Comment: Nice! Thanks for letting us know.